# ANSI C - Comparison Oddity

Tags: c, compare

I'm trying to compare an integer and a double:

```
printf("%d\n", pos<(td+tr));
            if(td <= pos < (td+tr))
            {}
```

The print statement evaluates the comparison `pos<(td+tr)` properly. The `if(td <= pos < (td+tr))` comparison does not evaluate properly.

Pos is an int: `int pos;`
td and tr are doubles: `double td,tr;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
td <= pos < (td+tr)
```

is evaluated left to right. So first

```
td <= pos
```

is evaluated to a truth value. And then that truth value is compared with `td+tr`.

That's not what you want. You want

```
if (td <= pos && pos < td+tr)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not do what you probably think it does, perhaps you need

```
td <= pos && pos < (td+tr)
```

?